# Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

Please, somebody should help me the gradle problem I encounter when upgrading android studio to version 4.1.2.
The error displayed was:
Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.2/gradle-4.1.2.pom'. Received status code 405 from server: Method Not Allowed
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

I tried my best but failed, please help.

Comment: have you installed **Google Repository**? You can check it in the SDK manager